# Flutter : How to create constructor in my Style class?

Tags: flutter, class, dart, constructor

I create a Style class in my flutter project. So I will use this Style class to call the TextStyle that I want to insert it in main.dart. I also create a constructor in Style class to get the color when the Style class called. I want to call the Style class in main.dart with `Style(Colors.black).header` . But there is an error while I try to create a constructor :
[image]

I need your help to solve this error, thank you very much :)

Comment: `class Style {
  Color styleColor;
  Style(this.styleColor);

  final TextStyle header = TextStyle(
    color: Colors.white,
    fontSize: 24,
    fontFamily: "Poppins",
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
  );
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access other instance members `styleColor` from the initializer of another. To solve this, you need to delay the initialization of `header` in some way, which could be accomplished by using the initializer list or making `header` a getter.

Using initializer list:

```dart
class Style {
  Color styleColor;
  
  Style(this.styleColor) : 
    header = TextStyle(
      color: styleColor,
      fontSize: 24,
      fontFamily: "Poppins",
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
    ),
    title1 = TextStyle(
      color: styleColor,
      fontSize: 24,
      fontFamily: "Poppins",
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
    );
  
  final TextStyle header;
  final TextStyle title1;
}
```

Making `header` a getter:

```dart
class Style {
  Color styleColor;
  
  Style(this.styleColor);
  
  TextStyle get header => TextStyle(
    color: styleColor,
    fontSize: 24,
    fontFamily: "Poppins",
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
  );

  TextStyle get title1 => TextStyle(
    color: styleColor,
    fontSize: 24,
    fontFamily: "Poppins",
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
  );
}
```

Comment: Wow, thank Christopher! But, how can I want to add another style in Style class. For example, I want to add title1 in Style class?

Comment: @BillRei Just add another entry to the initializer list or add a new getter. I added examples to the answers.

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you very much for your answer. I'm very happy to understand this problem :)